# Jetty process logged too many open files warning due which log file size increased up to 377 GB

Tags: java, unix, jetty, jetty-9, unix-socket

Jetty(v9.2.12) process logged **too many open files warning** due which log file size increased up to 377 GB and Jetty process was down.

```
2017-04-21 22:29:39.085:WARN:oejs.ServerConnector:qtp1921595561-113-acceptor-2@1a798c44-ServerConnector@5e3f861{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:18080}: 
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.accept(ServerConnector.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When this issue occurred Jetty process hold 4311 total open files. PFB result of lsof command. Maximum connection were created of sock, unix & FIFO type.
Can someone pls help me to understand why sock, unix & FIFO type connections Jetty creates.

Conn Type - Count
CHR - 6
DIR - 2
FIFO - 1023
IPv4 - 53
REG - 925
sock - 554
unix - 1748
**Total - 4311**

Result of ulimit -a

core file size (blocks, -c) unlimited 
data seg size (kbytes, -d) unlimited 
scheduling priority (-e) 0 file size (blocks, -f) unlimited 
pending signals (-i) 2066962 
max locked memory (kbytes, -l) 64 max memory size (kbytes, -m) unlimited 
open files (-n) 1024 
pipe size (512 bytes, -p) 8 POSIX 
message queues (bytes, -q) 819200 
real-time priority (-r) 0 
stack size (kbytes, -s) 10240 
cpu time (seconds, -t) unlimited 
max user processes (-u) 2066962 
virtual memory (kbytes, -v) 
unlimited file locks (-x) unlimited

Comment: What are your ulimit settings for the user running Jetty? run `ulimit -a` for the user running Jetty, and then edit/add it to your question.

Comment: core file size (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size   (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority (-e) 0
file size   (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals    (-i) 2066962
max locked memory  (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size  (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files    (-n) 1024
pipe size   (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority (-r) 0
stack size    (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time  (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes   (-u) 2066962
virtual memory   (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks   (-x) unlimited

Comment: You can edit your own question and add this information.